# ORDER BY before second request

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. One is a list of the dishes a user wants to cook associated with their level of priority. The second one associate a dish with its recipe.

I would like to do the following : Print all the dishes the user wants to cook with their recipe ordered by the priority level of each dish.

I tried doing the following :

```
        $req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT dish, priority FROM dish_task WHERE (username = :username) ORDER BY priority');
    $req->execute(['username' => $username]);
    $dish = $req->fetchAll();

    if ($dish != null) {

        //get right format -> (dish_1, ..., dish_n)
        $listDish = ""; 

        foreach ($dish as $d) {

            $listDish = $listDish . "'". strval($f['dish']) . "'" . ",";

        }

        $listDish = substr($listDish, 0, -1);

        $req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT dish, recipe FROM dish_data WHERE dish IN (' . $listDish . ')');
        $req->execute();

        $taskList = $req->fetchAll();

        echo json_encode($taskList);
```

The problem is that doing the second request seems to cancel the ORDER BY I did previously... So I don't know how I can manage to get what I want well ordered ?

Comment: I think you mean two tables, not two databases.

Comment: Yes u are right, I just edited

Comment: Don't do two queries, use one query with a `JOIN`.

Comment: @Barmar hmm never heard about this, how do u use it ?

Comment: Joins are one the basics of SQL.

Comment: Also, unrelated to current question but `$req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT dish, recipe FROM dish_data WHERE dish IN (' . $listDish . ')');` should be written that way if it were to be needed. Always parameterize queries.

Comment: @user3783243 Ty but I don't understand the differnece between what I've written and you've written

Comment: @Question1010 Sorry, typo `should be written` should have read `shouldn't be written`. The `$listDish` needs to be placeholders. Then the values actually bound in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single query that joins the two tables.

```
$req = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT dt.dish, dd.recipe
    FROM dish_task AS dt
    JOIN dish_data AS dd ON dt.dish = dd.dish
    WHERE (dt.username = :username) 
    ORDER BY dt.priority');
$req->execute(['username' => $username]);
$taskList = $req->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($taskList);
```